# ¿Que hace el "word" en Arduino y como hacerlo en C?

Tags: c, arduino

¿Alguien me podría explicar que es lo que hace esto?

```
unsigned int folioOxxo = 0;
folioOxxo = word(data2[16], data2[17]);
```

Entiendo que el tipo de dato *word* es como un *unsigned int*

Pero no comprendo bien si lo que hace es sumar los espacios de la matriz o que es lo que hace. Y ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer en C?

Comment: Está "explicado" aqui: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/conversion/wordcast/. No hay más info al respecto; me da la impresión que sirve para crear enteros de 16 bits sin importar la "endianess" de la arquitectura.